# CSS - Elastic layout, 1 fluid + 1 fixed column, center aligned

Tags: css, fixed, fluid, elasticlayout

This CSS challenge is really puzzling me.  Here's what I'm trying to do ...

- have an elastic layout (i.e. the container is max-width: 1200px min-width: 960px)
- have the container be center aligned.
- where the left column is fluid and expands to the highest possible width in the elastic constraints.
- and the right column is fixed to say 200px

Can anybody enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main part is keeping the left column stay fluid while the right is not.

The left column should have a wrapper, that wrapper should have a margin-right of 200px; The left column should be 100% width;

The right column should float right, have absolute positioning and have 200px of width.

Comment: Could you put together a jsbin or codepen (or code demo application of your choice)?